# Adding a secondary WHERE statement to PDO/MySql statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a PDO/MySQL database connection. My database holds content for various landing pages. To view these landing pages I enter ***localhost/landing_page_wireframe.php*** and append with ***?lps=X*** (where X represents the Thread_Segment) to display the particular page in the browser. I am now getting to second iterations of these pages and need to add a secondary classifier to follow "Thread_Segment" to distinguish which version I am trying to pull up. Here is a snippet of my current working query.

```
   <?php
    $result = "SELECT * FROM landing_page WHERE Thread_Segment = :lps";
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($result);
    $stmt->bindParam(':lps', $_GET['lps']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $thread = "";
    $threadSegment = "";
    $version = "";
    $categoryAssociation = "";
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $thread = $row["Thread"];
        $threadSegment = $row["Thread_Segment"];
        $version = $row["Version"];
        $categoryAssociation = $row["Category_Association"];
    }
?>
```

So I need to now change this to add in the secondary classifier to distinguish between versions. I would imagine my query would change to something like this:

```
$result = "SELECT * FROM landing_page WHERE Thread_Segment = :lps AND Version = :vrsn";
```

if this is correct so far, then where I am beginning to get lost is in the following PHP code.

```
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($result);
    $stmt->bindParam(':lps', $_GET['lps']);
    $stmt->execute();
```

I imagine I need to include some secondary iteration of this in my php to talk to the secondary classifier, but not totally sure how to go about this, and then I would imagine my url appendage would go from ***?lps=X*** to something like this ***?lps=X&vrsn=Y*** (Y representing the version).

I should state that I am somewhat new to PHP/MySql so the answer here may be simple, or may not even be possible. Perhaps I am not even going about this the correct way. Thought you all might be able to shed some insight, or direction for me to curve my research on the matter to. Thanks and apologies for any improper terminology, as I am definitely new to these technologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL change is as you describe. Just add another `bindParam` call to use that parameter:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare($result);
$stmt->bindParam(':lps', $_GET['lps']);
$stmt->bindParam(':vrsn', $_GET['vrsn']);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding another `bindParam()` should work here.

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare($result);
$stmt->bindParam(':lps', $_GET['lps']);
$stmt->bindParam(':vrsn', $_GET['vrsn']);
$stmt->execute();
```

You can access it via `?lps=X&vrsn=Y` but just as a warning, the query will fail if those `$_GET` params are not requested. I recommend defaulting it to something prior to sending it through the query:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare($result);

$lps = isset($_GET['lps']) ? $_GET['lps'] : 'default lps value';
$vrsn = isset($_GET['vrsn ']) ? $_GET['vrsn '] : 'default vrsn value';
$stmt->bindParam(':lps', $lps);
$stmt->bindParam(':vrsn', $vrsn);

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Fantastic, I actually had initially attempted the bindParam() method, but didn't put in the secondary $_GET param so it failed and I thought I was on the wrong path. Thanks for that insight and code education. I'm still learning what all this means. Big Thanks!